# SQL Server 2005 - removing table triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I remove all triggers from my tables. I have many tables, but about 20 of them have triggers and I want to remove them all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

run this:

```
SELECT 'DROP TRIGGER ' + name
FROM sysobjects
WHERE type = 'tr'
```

Then copy the results and run that in the query analyzer.   That'll get rid of all the triggers.